# Need to stop looping in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I am new to After Effects. I need to stop the animation at the end of the timeline. I've read this article and tried this solution "[Stop looping in after effect](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109016/stop-looping-in-after-effect)", however, when I get to Layer > Time, the only options I have are Time-Reverse Layer and Time Stretch. All the other ones are grayed out.

I'm guessing my settings are wrong somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the layer you are having problems with? Select the layer and press "u" to reveal all the keyframes on the layer first.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you don't want AE to loop playback when you're previewing?

Look in the Preview tab (Windows>Preview if it's not visible) and click the button that looks like a square loop symbol

[image]